# I'm looking for a way to control an iOS device with a Mac and execute pre-defined touch macros

Tags: macos, mac, macros, vnc, ios

I'm looking to perform automated testing on an app so I don't have to sit in front of my phone and perform the same repetitive tasks.

One thought is to use a VNC solution to connect with the iPhone, then run some sort of keyboard/mouse macro software on the Mac. But it won't be "smart" so I'm wondering if there's a way to incorporate some sort of AI into the process. This would mean OCR and some sort of logic engine. Does something like this exist?

Comment: I've seen this with Android, not sure if it can be done on iOS though.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Do you remember any more info - anything I can Google?

Answer (score 0):

iOS has an extensive set of built-in mechanisms (called UI Automation) to let you interact with on screen objects and areas.

As a result, there are a range of UI Automation testing solutions for iOS application, starting with the built-in [UI Automation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW1) features in Apples [Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) tool.

I would suggest you start with that and then look at some of the other ones available:

- [KIF](https://github.com/kif-framework/KIF)(which started out by using Apple's [Accessibility](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/iPhoneAccessibility/Introduction/Introduction.html) framework)
- [Appium](http://appium.io)(which works with iOS and Android and will be familiar if you've used [Selenium's Webdriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org))

Comment: Thanks for the info - this looks very helpful for developers. In my case, I'd like to automate an app that I don't have the source code for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually done this, but the simplest solution I can imagine would be some combination of iOSSimulator or TeamViewer and then [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/), which lets you do graphical scripting with UI elements.  It's difficult to describe, but go to that site and watch some of the Testing demo Videos.

I'd be concerned that it would be a rather brittle solution, though.